# Typescript coverage seems incorrect with tsc

Tags: typescript, testing, istanbul, test-coverage

It seems that the coverage is not correct with the function that I'd like to test :

```
public isSelfTweet = function(tweet: Tweet, twitterScreenName: string) {
    if(null == tweet || null == tweet.user || null == tweet.user.screen_name) {
        return false;
    }
    if(tweet.user.screen_name.toLowerCase() === twitterScreenName) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I write three tests and I have a 100% coverage :

- tweet = null, twitterScreenName = "toto"
- tweet with screen_name = "toto", twitterScreenName = "toto"
- tweet with screen_name = "toto", twitterScreenName = "tutu"

Here is the coverage which seems incorrect for me. I never have tested tweet not null, but tweet.user null for instance

[image]

In my package json :

```
"nyc": "^11.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you think is not working?

When I try the following in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html), the test works. By the way, you can't call `isSelfTweet` with null since you declare it has to be Tweet...

```
interface Tweet { 
    user:User
}

interface User { 
    screen_name:string
}

class Test {
    public isSelfTweet(tweet: Tweet, twitterScreenName: string) : boolean {
        if (tweet.user) {
            if (tweet.user.screen_name) {
                if (tweet.user.screen_name.toLowerCase() === twitterScreenName) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

let t = new Test()
let tweet = { user: {screen_name:"willy"}}

let test1 = t.isSelfTweet(tweet, "willy")
console.log(test1)   // returns true

let test2 = t.isSelfTweet(tweet, "wally")
console.log(test2)   // returns false
```

Comment: hi, it's not about the result of the method but more about the coverage. it indicates 100% of coverage but I never test against the third OR condition for instance.

Comment: "it indicates 100% of coverage" ... what exactly indicates 100% of coverage? do you use a test framework? Anyway, you could rewrite the test as follows ^